# JAVA_HOME, JAVA and ANT inconsistency

Tags: java, ubuntu, ant

I have Java installed correctly.

```
pc19@-H110:~$  java -version
java version "20.0.2" 2023-07-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.2+9-78)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.2+9-78, mixed mode, sharing)
```

but when I run by ant script. I get the following error

```
pc19@-H110:~/Documents/workspace/DCS$ ant all

We cannot run Java, please ensure you have Java installed.
  We have tried to execute /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-20/bin/java/bin/java but failed.
If you have installed Java in a unusual place you can set JAVA_HOME
to the directory containing the Java installation.
```

Comment: maybe share the steps of your installation for debugging purposes?

Comment: What is the value of `JAVA_HOME`? `java -version` works, so that means, `PATH` is pointing to the correct directory. `JAVA_HOME` should point to the parent directory of the `bin/` directory in which the `java` binary exists. This path that it tries to run `java` from is really weird `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-20/bin/java/bin/java`. If `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-20/bin/java` is the java binary, then `JAVA_HOME` should be `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-20`

Comment: The error suggests that you have set `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-20/bin/java`, it should be `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-20`.

Comment: Please, do not post multiple questions about the same problem.  You should merge this post and the one at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77124545/installing-ant-is-overriding-java-installation that contains other useful info.